# Binding controls inside ListBox to a source other than the source of ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, binding

I have a `ListBox` bound to a source which provides data to the text property of the controls inside. Now I'd like to bind `Foreground` property of my textboxes to a different source other than the one the main ListBox is bound to!

My listbox is bound to a ObservableCollection and I want my textblock Foreground property bound to textColor which is located in ViewModel

```
public SolidColorBrush textColor
{
    get { return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); }
}
```

both are in `ViewModel` class.
I tried using `Foreground="{Binding textColor}"` but it seems XAML doesn't see it at all, should I do anything in the page so that it can see it, or is it because the parent (`ListBox`) is using a different source?

**Edit :**

More details:

I have a `DataContext.cs` class which I have defined my tables in it.
I have a `ViewModel.cs` class which I have these in it

```
public class CViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CDataContext myDB;

    public CViewModel(string DBConnectionString)
    {
        myDB = new CDataContext(DBConnectionString);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Groups> _allGroups;
    public ObservableCollection<Groups> AllGroups
    {
        get { return _allGroups; }
        set
        {
            _allGroups = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AllGroups");
        }
    }

    public string textColor
    {
        get { return "Tomato"; }
    }
}
```

Then I have my XAML file `MainPage.xaml`:

```
....
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox Margin="0,8,0,0"  toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding AllGroups}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  BorderThickness="4">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Orange" Width="125" Height="125" Margin="6" Tap="Counterlist_OnTap">
                    <TextBlock Name="gname" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="ccl" Margin="0,0,0,-5" Foreground="{Binding textColor}" Text="{Binding Count}" FontSize="26" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
....
```

I also set `DataContext` of my `MainPage` to `ViewModel` in code behind:

```
this.DataContext = App.ViewModel;
```

Comment: This should work fine. I took a default DataBound app, added your property to `ItemViewModel` and added the foreground binding at the end of line 36 in MainPage.xaml and when ran in the emulator it set the colour of the textblock correctly. Please provide a complete example which recreates your issue and we'll help identify where your issue is.

Comment: You've now defined `textColor` twice. Is it a string or a SolidColorBrush?

Comment: Yeah I changed it to string as I thought it would need string when I read it in XAML !

Comment: If you're setting it via binding you'll need to set the type correctly. The XAML parsers will try and convert strings when doing the initial parse but when binding properties you don't get this automatic conversion.

Comment: I changed it to SolidColorBrush , it doesn't work again. But I did try it to a control outside my ListBox and it works perfectly fine, so the problem is that when I put it inside the ListBox it cant find the property as it only sees Binding through the ListBox data context which is bound to a different source ! what can I do now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `textColor` property is part of the `CViewModel`, not the `Groups` object that is the datacontext within the ItemTemplate.

Within the ItemTemplate you can reach out to the parent ViewModel with the following Element binding:

```
<TextBlock Name="ccl" Margin="0,0,0,-5"
           Foreground="{Binding ElementName=ContentPanel, Path=DataContext.textColor}"
           Text="{Binding Count}" FontSize="26"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is declare a static class (e.g. a singleton with per-instance access) and explicitly set the property binding to look in that class instead of the parent-bound model.

**Bottom line:** Just set the `Source` explicitly through a `StaticResource`.

Comment: Can you please show me how it is done, as I'm not very familiar with Windows Phone and XAML terms !